# Using generics for single implementation of inheritance from classes with a common parent class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a class that is inherited by a number of other classes. For each of those I need a subclass where I override one method. But this method is actually defined in the base class, so it would be nice if I could use generics and use a single implementation. Something like this:

```
public class MyBase
{
    void myMethod()
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}

public class A extends MyBase
{
}   

public class B extends MyBase
{
}

public class MyCommonSubclass <T extends MyBase> extends T //Can't do it like this
{
    @Override
    void myMethod()
    {
        doSomethingElse():
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to achieve that? (I don't think so, but I'm asking anyway in case I'm wrong.)
(And yes, this problem is a result of bad design, but for now I have to live with that.)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are doing.  The generic parameter is not used anywhere.  Generics are not a substitute for inheritance, they're different.  You'll have to explain better what your actual use case is here for us to be able to give you any help.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot extend a free variable type and an interface cannot extend a class.

The closest is implement a kind of [Trait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)) (not directly supported in Java).

```
// this interface reverse the type parameter restriction
public interface RequiredToRestrictTraitToHaveNameMethod {
    String name();
}

public static class MyBase implements RequiredToRestrictTraitToHaveNameMethod {
    public String name() {
        return this.getClass().getCanonicalName();
    }
}

// a normal common class/trait
public interface TraitFoo {
    default void foo() {
        System.out.printf("- FOO %s!%n", this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}

// a special type restricted common class/trait
public interface TraitBar extends RequiredToRestrictTraitToHaveNameMethod {
    default void bar() {
        System.out.printf("- BAR %s!%n", name()); // here is your T type
    }
}

public static class MySuper extends MyBase implements TraitBar {
}

public static class MySuperBad extends MyBase implements TraitBar {
    // here is your override
    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "OverridedNameOfMyParent";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MySuper().bar();
    new MySuperBad().bar();
}
```

with output

```
- BAR com.computermind.sandbox.observer.Test.MySuper!
- BAR OverridedNameOfMyParent!
```

Using interfaces and default implementations you can achieve a similar behavior but, without knowing what exactly you want to do (for that you will have to create another request in SO) I can't give you a complete example.